# How to set up a binding in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I've got a window with a field like this:

```
public partial class VariablesWindow : Window
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Variables { get; private set; }
```

And then in the window's XAML, I've created a ListView. How do I set the ItemsSource to bind to `Variables`?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="???"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what ChrisF posted would work...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" />
```

But you may need to explicity set the DataContext.

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Yes! Needed to set the `DataContext` too. The other answers were missing this :)

Comment: @Ralph: not quite true. The bindings will work fine *unless* someone sets the `DataContext` to something else.

Comment: @Jon: I didn't touch the DataContext property previously... I'm assuming by default it points to the control itself, not to the Window.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Variables}" />
```

I'm not in a position to double check this right now, so I'm not 100% of whether the `Path=` is needed or not.

There's more information on the binding syntax on the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx). All their examples have the `Path=` syntax.

And you will have to set the `DataContext`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Variables}" />
```

However, you may find it more useful to bind directly to keys or values, which you would do like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Variables.Values}" />
```

**Update:** These bindings will work as long as your `DataContext` is `null` or equal to `this`. Otherwise, you would need to use something more cumbersome, like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=x:Type Window}}, Path=Variables}
```

For binding help, take a look at [this superb cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/22/wpf-data-binding-cheat-sheet-update-the-internationalization-fix.aspx).

Comment: direct link: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf (it's hidden on the page you linked to!)

Comment: @Ralph: I know. I didn't want to hotlink the PDF. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it's a bit ridiculously verbose:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:VariablesWindow, AncestorLevel=1}
```

Doesn't seem like the best way to do it.